# Can I specify multiple hostnames in a single certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a cloudera managed Hadoop cluster where I had installed SSL certificates on all servers. Unfortunately, the host name on the servers are not the same as the one configured over dns.

When run hostname -f it gives: server1.x
But when I do nslookup from a client machine i get: server1.x.y

Obviously accessing server1.x.y from the browser gives identity error since it trusts only server1.x I was wondering if I could add server1.x.y in the Subject Alternative Name and would the browser start trusting the certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the SAN extension is to have a (typed) list of subject names that are all considered valid. You could use that to add any additional names that you want clients to be able to use.

However, it sounds like you don't actually need multiple names in this scenario? It sounds like only one of those two names actually work in practice (the one that exists in DNS) and then it would probably be better to just clean up your configuration such that you consistently only use one of the names instead of having a confusing mix of both.
I think such a cleanup appears much preferable compared to committing further to the confusion by adding both names in SAN.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I specify multiple hostnames in a single certificate?

Yes